# How to assign types/values to variables in classes

Tags: python, list, class, range

Here, I'm trying to make an object (A 20 sided die) with the following qualities; Name, and Number of sides.

The way I wanna build this is that when I call the class (or make a new "Dice" object,) all I need to tell the code is what to name the dice, and how many sides there are on it. (1 to 20, in this case.)

```
class Dice: #The class itself, the outline for the Dice to come.

    def __init__(self, name, nsides): 

    #The initializing bit, along with                      
    #the stats I want these objects to carry.

        self.name = name("")                     
        self.nsides = nsides(list(range(int, int)))

    #I was thinking the above code tells python that the value nsides,                                                                                                 
    #when referencing Dice, is a list, that is being organized into  
    #a range, where the items in said range would always be integers.

d20 = Dice("d20", (1, 21))

#This is where I'm creating an instance of Dice, followed by filling out 
#the fields name and the integers in nsides's list/range.

print(d20.nsides)



print(d20.nsides)

#The expected outcome is the following being printed:

#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

#What I get however is this error upon running:

#Expected type 'int'. got 'Type[int]' instead.
```

Comment: `self.nsides = [i for i in range(nsides[0], nsides[1])]`

Comment: In your initialization, why do you call `name()` and `nsides()`? You've passed in the arguments, they are not pointers to functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is occurring as you are parsing the 'range' class a new Int Class object, not an integer. However there are other errors, such as trying the call a string object: name("") which shouldn't work.

Your init class can be amended to:

```
def __init__(self, name, nsides):

    self.name = name
    self.nsides = list(range(*nsides))
```

The "*" will unpack your tuple into useable integers for the range class to use

Comment: So I corrected my code, and it worked great! (Thanks by the way!) 

But just a quick question; why does "*" unpack the tuple. Also, why is the list variable being considered as a tuple? Are they the same thing? I read that one is "immutable" or something like that...

Comment: An object that is surrounded in curly brackets ('spam', 'eggs') is a tuple. A list is defined in square brackets [ 'spam', 'eggs'], therefore you are sending the dice class a tuple, not a list. In this case, either would work. You are correct however that a tuple is immutable. With regards asterisk operator, check out information on *args and **kwargs. It will give you some useful insight into how python classes work.

Comment: Thanks my guyyyy!

Cheers, wish me luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Dice: #The class itself, the outline for the Dice to come.
    ''' param:
        name : str  # name to given,
        nsides : tuple/ list iterateable variable 
        return: None
    '''
    def __init__(self, name, nsides): 

        # passing the name (user input ) to class object self.name 
        self.name = name     
        # doing list comprehension                
        self.nsides = [ i for i in range(nsides[0],nsides[1])]
        # range function works as range(a,b)-> [a,b)  a is incluse and b is exclusive
        # and it is incremented by 1 default 
        ''' it is same as 
        self.nsides = []
        for i in range(nsides[0],nsides[1]):
            self.nsides+=[i] # or self.nsides.append(i)
        '''
d20 = Dice("d20", (1, 21))
print(d20.nsides)
# output [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```